# Schedule generating calendar software

Tags: windows, time-management, calendar, scheduling

I am looking for software that has two main features,

1. A calendar feature
2. A day schedule feature

I would like to use the calendar to log tasks which I know will occur at a certain date within a certain time interval. Once I have logged all tasks for the week, I would like the calendar to generate a daily schedule which I can print out and use for that particular day.

The only program I know that could probably do this is [Microsoft Project](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Project); however, that would really be an overkill since MS project contains lots features fit for managing entire companies whereas I just need to manage me.